# Magento Add product to cart programmatically - Works in one website, fails in other

Tags: addtocart, programmatically

I have a magento store with two websites for Italian and Spanish market. I perform a php page to add items to cart programatically, but it works in Spain but not in Italy.

See sample code that works on ES but not in IT.

```
umask(0);
Mage::app();
$session = Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' =>> 'frontend')); 
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
$cart->init();
$cart->addProduct(140616, 3);
$session->setCartWasUpdated(true);
$cart->save();
```

In var_dump afther `$cart->init();` I see that the cart in IT dont load customer data.

Var_Dump in ES

```
object(Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart)[80]
  protected '_summaryQty' => null
  protected '_productIds' => null
  protected '_data' => 
    array (size=1)
      'quote' => 
        object(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote)[82]
          protected '_eventPrefix' => string 'sales_quote' (length=11)
          protected '_eventObject' => string 'quote' (length=5)
          protected '_customer' =>
            object(Mage_Customer_Model_Customer)[136]
              protected '_eventPrefix' => string 'customer' (length=8)
              protected '_eventObject' => string 'customer' (length=8)
              protected '_errors' => 
                array (size=0)
                  empty
              protected '_attributes' => null
              protected '_addresses' => null
              protected '_addressesCollection' => null
```

Var_Dump in IT

```
object(Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart)[81]
  protected '_summaryQty' => null
  protected '_productIds' => null
  protected '_data' => 
    array (size=1)
      'quote' => 
        object(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote)[83]
          protected '_eventPrefix' => string 'sales_quote' (length=11)
          protected '_eventObject' => string 'quote' (length=5)
          protected '_customer' => null
          protected '_addresses' => null
          protected '_items' => 
            object(Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Quote_Item_Collection)[136]
              protected '_quote' => 
                &object(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote)[83]
              protected '_productIds' => 
                array (size=11)
                  0 => int 139190
                  1 => int 139167
                  2 => int 73844
```

Any sugestion?

Thanks

Comment: yes need to add  store .. On your code add this `Mage::app("StoreCOde",'Storetype');`  instead of `Mage::app();`

Comment: Perfect solution!! Now it works perfect, As you suggest I change <pre>Mage::app();</pre> with <pre>Mage::app('11');</pre>. Thanks for your help! Add an answer if you want to check it as solution. Thanks from Spain.

Comment: add ..please check..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per as comment. You need  to initialize  Mage::app() for each store.

SO just  need to add store on Mage::app() .

**Use:** `Mage::app("StoreCOde",'Storetype');`

instead of `Mage::app()`